# Correct way to dipose wpf control in reloadable parent control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dispose

I have `WebBrowser` control into my `UserControl`. This `UserControl` is showing depending of `DataTemplateSelector` rules. So it's displayed and hided sequentially. (Imagine that I have the list of customer's orders and clicking on list item I load UserControl into `ContentPresenter`.)
According to many problems with memleaks of `WebBrowser` it's recommended to dispose it. 
So I call in that way.

```
private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser.Dispose();
}
```

But I noticed that if usually stacktrace is ctor, loaded, unloaded but sometimes wpf engine doesn't recreate the UserControl calling ctor but get it from cache (if I undestand correctly) and so i get disposed browser in `UserControl` as Unloaded method disposes it.

**How can I dispose a disposable control, that is embed in redispayable `UserControl`?**

Comment: As I have understood your problem is not to dispose a WebBrowser-Control, but if usercontrol will be reused the WebBrowser-Control is disposed, am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. I need save WebBrowser disposing but yes if usercontrol will be reused the WebBrowser-Control is disposed. And i'd like be ensure that i dispose WebBrowser if UserControl will never be reused. May be Unloaded not best place

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `WebBrowser` Control instance in the `Loaded` event of your UserControl and dispose it in the `Unloaded` event handler, i.e. instead of defining the control in your XAML markup you create it in the code-behind of the same view,

Comment: Or it coud be possible attach creation/disposing to VisibilityChanged.

Comment: And...? Why don't you implement it?

Comment: As I get from many articles and questions anyway after dispose WebBrowser hold some unmanaged resources, and if to create new Webbrowser each time i'm afraid they will be normally disposed, and there will be new instance each time, but i'll get more memory used. Now i'm coding it.